# How to bulk update doc page size to make the page size consistent?

Tags: node.js, ms-word, libreoffice, .doc, soffice

I have a bunch of word document (.doc) files and all have different paper size format like "letter" or "A4" or "A3".

I want to convert all those docs formats to the "A4" size without opening those files.

Is there any way to convert those files in a batch process using any tools or any library?